# Setting value for a textbox MVC 4 ASP

Tags: asp.net-mvc, css, asp.net-mvc-4, razorgenerator

I have the following code in my view .cshtml

```
...
<td class="Centrado">
<input class="plato" value="" id="TComida">                                                                                
</td>
....
```

and i want to set a value that comes from the controller, the value is from the class Comida the property Price,

```
....
@model Util.Comida
Util.Comida menu = new Util.Comida();
menu= (Util.Comida)ViewData["Comida"];
....
```

¿What can i do to set the value menu.Price to my input class="plato" value="" id="TComida"
without losing the css styles aplied thx to my class="plato"?

I have checked that the object menu is correctly populated with data from the controller.
Sorry for my english and thx in advance.

Comment: `<input class="plato" value="@menu.Price" id="TComida">`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't really what you should be doing in a view:

```
@model Util.Comida
Util.Comida menu = new Util.Comida();
menu= (Util.Comida)ViewData["Comida"];
```

If the model is a `Util.Comida` then the controller should supply an instance of one to the view.  For example, when returning the view in the controller:

```
var model = new Util.Comida();
// set properties, invoke logic, etc.
return View(model);
```

Then in the view the model is inherently present in the `Model` property.  So use one of its values, you can reference that property.  For example:

```
<input class="plato" value="@Model.Price" id="TComida">
```

Or even use an HTML helper to emit the `input` tag, which can bring more framework functionality with it.  Something like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Price, new { id = "TComida", @class = "plato" })
```

The point is that the controller provides the view with the model, the view doesn't *create* the model or invoke any logic on it.  Code in a view should generally be limited to binding to properties on a model.  Actual logic goes in the model, and the controller invokes that logic and provides the resulting model state to the view.